# Permisos para escribir salida de una consulta mysql a archivo

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-server

tengo un problema de permisos en MYSQL a la hora de exportar los datos de una salida SELECT desde MYSQL me responde :

> ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/ (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

He probado varias cosas. Lo primer que tengo que decir es que el archivo mysqld.cnf la variable secure_file_priv lo tengo así:

```
 local-infile = 1
 secure_file_priv = ""
```

Esto es así para solucionar el problema de permisos al hacer desde MYSQL el:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
```

He ahí la cuestion, he intentado poner la ruta al directorio donde quiero la salida pero  me da un error al reiniciar el mYSQL (failed), osea he tenido que volver a comillarlo. Luego me he ido a /etc/my.cnf y ahí si me ha dejado poner:

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv = /home/LOTES
```

Si me deja reiniciar pero no me hace efecto. Luego probe a cambiar el dueño y los permisos del directorio, y los tengo así:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql  mysql  4096 jul 28 12:06 LOTES
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar. Pero desde fuera de MYSQL si me funciona:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p  < /home/LOTES/externo.txt > /home/LOTES/lotes2.txt
```

Ya me he quedado sin opciones, se que es un  problema de permisos por que desde fuera de MYSQL me funciona y desde dentro el error es de permisos, osea el comando es correcto.
¿Como lo puedo hacer para que funcione el LOAD DATA LOCAL y desde MYSQL pueda exportar el archivo?

Vale voy seguir por aqui por que es más fácil poner el código. Yo creo que es como dice Bryro el apparmor. He visto varios post al respecto. He modificado el siguiente archivo :

> sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

He añadido esto "/data/ rw" :

```
 Allow pid, socket, socket lock file access
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock.lock rw,
**/data/ rw,**
```

Ahora cuando ejecuto:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/home/carlos/Escritorio/LOTES/prueba.txt' 
FROM pet;
```

Me responde:

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file
```

'/home/carlos/Escritorio/LOTES/prueba.txt' (OS errno 13 -
Permission denied)

Pero los permisos estan bien, ¿ debo de añadir algo más al archivo apparmor?

Comment: luego de hacer el cambio al `secure_file_priv` reiniciaste la instancia? as un `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%secure%";` para ver si se aplico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

primero editamos el archivo **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf**

```
[mysqld]
# allow INTO OUTFILE file and LOAD DATA INFILE to this directory
secure_file_priv=/home/LOTES
```

luego de hacer el cambio al `secure_file_priv` creamos el directorio si no existe:

```
sudo su
cd /home
mkdir LOTES
chown mysql:mysql LOTES
chmod a+rw LOTES
```

luego reiniciamos la instancia y validamos el cambio:

```
sudo su
service mysql restart
mysql
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%secure%";
+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                   |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| require_secure_transport | OFF                     |
| secure_auth              | ON                      |
| secure_file_priv         | /home/LOTES/            |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.07 sec)
mysql> quit
Bye
```

para ver si se aplico.

luego valida que el **apparmor** no este molestado con:

```
$ aa-status
apparmor module is loaded.
```

si sale que esta cargado hacemos:

```
/etc/apparmor/local/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

y agregas la ruta:

```
/home/LOTES rw,
/home/LOTES** rw,
```

y por ultimo ejecutamos

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Comment: BUenos días @Bryro lo siento pero no he podido responderte ántes. LO he intentado pero cuando modifico 'secure_file_priv=/home/LOTES' no me deja reiniciar. Si me voy  a /var/log/mysql me sale este error:secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /home/carlos/Escritorio/LOTES
2023-07-31T09:18:04.220170Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
 Los permisos de LOTES estan así, lo cree como tú has puesto: drwxrwxrwx  2 mysql  mysql  4096 jul 31 11:03 LOTES

Comment: Vale ya me funciono !!!! He seguido  tus pasos @Bryro pero al revés. El problema venia al modificar la variable "secure_file_priv=/home/LOTES" que no me dejaba reiniciar el mysql y ahí me atascaba. Lo he ignorado y seguido haciendo lo que has escrito, y al final del todo he reiniciado el mysql, y sin problema ha funcionado a la primera. Muchas gracias!!!